# How does one break a string down by capital letters with PHP?

Tags: php, split, explode, camelcasing

I have a string: `CamelCaseString`

I want to explode(), split(), or some better method on capital letters to break this string down into the individual words.

What's the simplest way to do this?

**--- SOLUTION UPDATE ---**

This link is to a slightly different question, but I think the answer will generally be more useful than the answers to the current question on this page:
[How can I add a space in string at capital letters, but keep continuous capitals together using PHP and a Regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611617/how-can-i-add-a-space-in-string-at-capital-letters-but-keep-continuous-capitals)

Comment: The problem with the normal `explode()` function is that it will remove the so called "needle" (in your case the capital letter(s)). So the usual explode wont do the job.

Comment: Yeah, I tried `preg_split('/[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ]/', "CamelCaseString", -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)` But that returns an array without the upper case characters

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use regular expressions.
Try this: `preg_match_all('/[A-Z][^A-Z]*/', "CamelCaseString", $results);`

The array containing all the words will be saved in $results[0].

Comment: That's true, $results will be: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Camel [1] => Case [2] => String ) )`

Comment: It won't work for a string like, say, "MySQL". It'll give you "My", "S", "Q", "L", which may not be what you want

Comment: I also had to check to make sure the string is not all caps (every letter splits), is not all lower case (all data is lost), and a few other things.  It's not perfect, but it's pretty good.

Comment: see this question instead for an answer that will generally be more useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611617/how-can-i-add-a-space-in-string-at-capital-letters-but-keep-continuous-capitals

Answer (score 8):

This seems to work too

```
$split = preg_split("/(?<=[a-z])(?![a-z])/", "CamelCaseString", -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

And it won't break up longer runs of uppercase letters. I.e. "MySQL", will become "My" and "SQL"

Answer (score -1):

The split() function has been deprecated so I would look for a solution that uses some other function.

Comment: Well, yes, he was specifically asking for another solution than `split`

Comment: His question has been edited. It originally asked for how to do it with split(). Thanks for the down vote when my point if perfectly valid.