# How can I add a space in string at capital letters, but keep continuous capitals together using PHP and a Regex?

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to add a space to a string on capital letters using a PHP method like `preg_replace()` and a regex, but I only want to add a space on the first capital letter when they are continuous.  I also would like the regex to know that the last capital in a continuous string of capitals should be the next capital to put a space before.

These strings are examples:

```
TodayILiveInTheUSAWithSimon
USAToday
IAmSOOOBored
```

become:

```
 Today I Live In The USA With Simon
 USA Today
 I Am SOOO Bored
```

Can this be done, and how?

*This question ( [Regular expression, split string by capital letter but ignore TLA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097901/regular-expression-split-string-by-capital-letter-but-ignore-tla) ), seems to accomplish this with .net.*

**WORKING SOLUTION**

Here is the complete code that I use:

```
$string = 'TodayILiveInTheUSAWithSimon';
$regex = '/(?<!^)((?<![[:upper:]])[[:upper:]]|[[:upper:]](?![[:upper:]]))/';
$string = preg_replace( $regex, ' $1', $string );
```

Both of these regex's work:

```
/(?<!^)((?<![[:upper:]])[[:upper:]]|[[:upper:]](?![[:upper:]]))/
/((?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?=[A-Z][a-z]))/
```

The first one is from @Regexident's solution below, and is very very slightly faster than the second one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Find:

```
(?<!^)((?<![[:upper:]])[[:upper:]]|[[:upper:]](?![[:upper:]]))
```

Replace:

```
 $1
```

note the space before `$1`

Edit: fix.

Comment: What PHP methods should I use to accomplish this with this regex?

Comment: @T.BrianJones: That would be [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `preg_replace(): Compilation failed: POSIX named classes are supported only within a class at offset 4` when I execute this: `echo preg_replace( '((?<![:upper:]|^)[:upper:]|(?<!^)[:upper:](?![:upper:]))', ' $1', $string );`

Comment: Please see fixed answer. I forgot that PHP requires double brackets around `:upper:`, my bad. My PHP is a bit dusty, unlike my regex. :P