# php explode for a special case

Tags: php, explode

I have a huge text file which I want to explode into an array.

The words in it doesnt have spaces, but each word starts with a capital letter.

How can I explode it to an array taking the capital letters as seperator,without losing the charector?

AppleBallCat should be 1 => Apple 2=> Ball 3=> Cat

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920155/how-does-one-break-a-string-down-by-capital-letters-with-php

Comment: Sorry! couldnt find that before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP explode the string, but treat words in quotes as a single word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202435/php-explode-the-string-but-treat-words-in-quotes-as-a-single-word)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$s = 'AppleBallCat';
$a = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $s);
unset($a[0]);
var_dump($a);
```

> ```
> array(3) {
>   [1]=>
>   string(5) "Apple"
>   [2]=>
>   string(4) "Ball"
>   [3]=>
>   string(3) "Cat"
> }
> ```